# htaccess same rewrite rules for different pages not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have two different pages in my site, i need url rewriting for these two pages. I have tried this code but not working only one is working another not working.

In my htaccess

first rule :

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ view.php?link=$1
```

Second rule :

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ list.php?name=$1
```

Only first one working, can any one tell me how to solve this.

Comment: They have the same regexp, that's why only one is working(First one)

Comment: Yes, can you tell how to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be able to differentiate between the two types of URLs. Given this:

```
http://example.com/foo
```

Does it go to `/view.php?link=foo`? or does it go to `/list.php?name=foo`?

One way you can do this is prefix the dynamic part of the URL with something, like:

```
http://example.com/view/foo
http://example.com/list/foo
```

So the rule would look like:

```
RewriteRule ^view/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ view.php?link=$1  
RewriteRule ^list/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ list.php?name=$1
```